# How to enumerate SQL Server role members with Powershell?

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell, sql-server

I have a powershell script to enumerate the members of SQL Server role members using powershell. I have this script

```
<... cut the connection details for brevity, 
$SqlInstance is a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server object ...>

$db = $SqlInstance.Databases[$Database]

foreach ($role in $db.Roles)
{
    foreach ($memberlist in $role.EnumMembers)
    {
        foreach ($member in $memberlist)
        {
            Write-Host ($member)
        }       
    }
}
```

I get output like this:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection EnumMembers()
```

How do I actually see the role members? Confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out I needed `()` on the end of `EnumMembers`, DOH!